# batched message listener for spring (extending from DefaultMessageListenerContainer)

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-batch, spring-jms

I have a basic JMS related question in spring.
Rather than having to consume a single message at a time, it would be convenient to batch messages for a short duration (say a few seconds) and process them in bulk (thereby doing things in bulk). I see that java only provides an `onMessage` call that gives a single message at a time. I came across [BatchMessageListenerContainer](http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2010/04/batchmessagelistenercontainer-using.html) which seems to do this exactly. The recipe is ported to spring-batch where it is being used.

I wanted to know if there are any fundamental problem in the approach itself? If there are no problems, we can propose to the spring folks to add this in the `spring-jms` artifact itself (without needing to resort to use `spring-batch` whatsoever).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your need is to process the messages in parallel you can use **DefaultMessageListenerContainer** in your spring project without the necessity for spring batch. You set the attribute concurrent consumers to the number of partitions you want.

```
 @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListener() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer listener = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        **listener.setConcurrentConsumers(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(JmsConstant.CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS_SIZE)));**
        // listener.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentConsumers);
        listener.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) queueConnectionFactory().getObject());
        listener.setDestination((Destination) jmsQueue().getObject());
        listener.setMessageListener(this);
        listener.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        listener.setSessionTransacted(true);

        return listener;
    }
```

Otherwise, if you're using spring batch, you can use remote chunking and BatchMessageListenerContainer, you can find an example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotechunking